# How would I translate this weird PHP line to something less compact?

Tags: php, debugging, reset, phpstan, php-8.1

I have this code, part of a function I use to determine if a given string is a reserved PHP keyword (since PHP has no function for this built in):

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $string . '; ?>');

if (is_array($tokens))
    return reset($tokens[1]) !== T_STRING; // Madness...
```

It's making PHPStan bark:

> Parameter #1 $array of function reset expects array|object, array<int, int|string>|string given.

I cannot figure out why, but want the error to go away, so I'm trying to "unfold" this compact line, but I realize that I don't understand what it's doing. Can you explain and help me? I often find that splitting things up into separate lines/operations make PHPStan stop barking.

Comment: `reset` is described here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php#refsect1-function.reset-returnvalues

Comment: @deceze Your point being...?

Answer (score 0):

PHPStan rightfully marks your code as wrong. In your example `$tokens` is always an array because that's what `token_get_all` returns.

Perhaps you meant to iterate over `$tokens` and check the type of the iterated value like this:

```php
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $string . '; ?>');

foreach ($tokens as $t) {
    \PHPStan\dumpType($t); // array{int, string, int}|string
    if (is_array($t)) {
        \PHPStan\dumpType($t); // array{int, string, int}
        return $t[0] !== T_STRING; // this was the intended logic?
    }
}
```

Example on the PHPStan playground: https://phpstan.org/r/63db568c-94d2-4c5f-bc7b-611448d4a96c